# Shoulda validate_format_of . not_with has problem in framework (or in my understanding)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, shoulda

I put the following code into an RSpec test:

```
it { should validate_format_of(:email).not_with('test@test')}
```

and setup the actual class with:

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :format => /\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i
```

And when I run the tests I get:

**Failures:
  1) User
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_format_of(:email).not_with('test@test')}
     Expected errors to include "can't be blank" when email is set to "test@test", got errors: ["name can't be blank (nil)", "email is invalid (\"test@test\")"]
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in '**

When I do a passing test like:

```
it { should validate_format_of(:email).with('adam@trimediatlantic.com')}
```

Everything works as expected.  Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a framework problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you meant 'test@test' for the failing test value, correct?

Answer (score 27):

Try this instead:

```
it { should_not allow_value("test@test").for(:email) }
```

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into a similar problem  Turns out you need to invoke the [`with_message`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_format_of_matcher.rb) method and supply the exact error message as a string, or a regex that matches the error message. Doing so will convince the validate_format_of to cease its stubborn insistence that format errors result in "can't be blank" messages, and actually pass.  For example:

```
it { should validate_format_of(:email).not_with('test@test')}
```

becomes

```
it { should validate_format_of(:email).not_with('test@test').with_message(/invalid/)}
```

This sure looks like a bug in the shoulda library.

Comment: Also note that you need to invoke with_message on "with" cases as well, or else it'll errantly succeed because it's looking for "cant be blank" in the error list of the field being validated.

Answer (score 0):

From Shouda Matchers 2.0, validate_format_of was deprecated. Please use `allow_value`.

```
should validate_format_of(:email).with('user@example.com')
```

to

```
should allow_value('user@example.com').for(:email )
```

from thoughtbot blog: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/shoulda-matchers-2-0#validate_format_of