# Rails, shoulda and rspec, Column Not Null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda

I am not able to get my tests passing for where the field can be empty string but where it can't be null.

I used this [stackeroverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012871/how-do-default-0-and-null-false-differ-for-integer-fields-in-migrations) for a litte help

But can't find much more to help me.

In my schema.rb file I see:

```
t.string   "CUSTID",        :limit => 8,     :default => "",     :null => false
```

When I run an rspec test against this, my validates still allows it to be null. Could you please explain why my test (below) would fail?

```
it 'CUSTID may not be nil' do
  should_not allow_value(nil).for(:CUSTID)
end
```

then I tried these validations methods separate in the model.

```
validates :TNCUSTID, :allow_nil => false
validates :TNCUSTID,  :format => {:with => /^(CU)(\d{6})$|(^$)/ }
```

and even leaving the validation out completely

```
#validates :TNCUSTID, :allow_nil => false
```

In all cases my "Should not be nil" test case fails for custid

---

My ultimate goal is to say that the value can be either this format (regex above), can be empty string BUT is can never be null according to the database.

Can someone please enlighten me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use validates

```
validates :TNCUSTID, presence: true
validates :TNCUSTID, :format => {:with => /^(CU)(\d{6})$|(^$)/ }
```

And in your tests

```
should validate_presence_of :TNCUSTID
```

And for email

```
should validate_format_of(:email).not_with('test@test').with_message(/invalid/)
```

From [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316550/1197775)